# Understanding why onClick() is Called Even After onDispatchTouchEvent() Returns True

Tags: java, android, user-interface, onclick, ontouch

Lets say, in an Android app, we want to have the ability to temporarily and reliably ignore all user touches at any moment.

From the research I have done on stack-overflow as well as [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZAoJU-nUyI), [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events), and [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/a175a5b/core/java/android/view/View.java), the agreed-upon solution seems to be something like this:

(Code of MainActivity.java):

```
// returning true should mean touches are ignored/blocked
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent pEvent) {

    if (disableTouches) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(pEvent);
    }

}
```

However, when we introduce the [Android Monkey Exerciser Tool](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkey) and send touch events to the app at a rapid rate, it becomes apparent that pigs begin to fly at the quantum level -- we can get calls to `onClick()` even after/during times where "blockTouches" has been set to true.

**MY QUESTION IS: Why is that? -- Is this a normal Android behavior, or did I make a mistake in my code? :)**

Note: *I have already ruled out the possibility of `onClick()` being called by user input other than touches (and therefore being uncontrolled by the `onDispatchTouchEvent()` method)... by adding "—-pct-touch 100" to the monkey command.*

Here is the code I am using for this test:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    View rootView; // turns black when "touch rejection" is in progress

    View allowedButton;
    View notAllowedButton;

    // Used to decide whether to process touch events.
    // Set true temporarily when notAllowedButton is clicked.
    boolean touchRejectionAnimationInProgress = false;

    int errorCount = 0; // counting "unexpected/impossible" click calls

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rootView = findViewById(R.id.rootView);

        allowedButton = findViewById(R.id.allowedButton);
        notAllowedButton = findViewById(R.id.notAllowedButton);

        allowedButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        notAllowedButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        allowedButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        notAllowedButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

    }

    // returning true should mean touches are ignored/blocked
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent pEvent) {

        if (touchRejectionAnimationInProgress) {
            Log.i("XXX", "touch rejected in dispatchTouchevent()");
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.dispatchTouchEvent(pEvent);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View viewThatWasClicked){

        Log.i("XXX", "onClick() called.  View clicked: " + viewThatWasClicked.getTag());

        //checking for unexpected/"impossible"(?) calls to this method
        if (touchRejectionAnimationInProgress) {
            Log.i("XXX!", "IMPOSSIBLE(?) call to onClick() detected.");
            errorCount ++;
            Log.i("XXX!", "Number of unexpected clicks: " + errorCount);
            return;
        } // else proceed...

        if (viewThatWasClicked == allowedButton) {
            // Irrelevant
        } else if (viewThatWasClicked == notAllowedButton) {
            // user did something that is not allowed.
            touchRejectionAnimation();
        }

    }

    // When the user clicks on something "illegal,"
    // all user input is ignored temporarily for 200 ms.
    // (arbitrary choice of duration, but smaller is better for testing)
    private void touchRejectionAnimation() {

        Log.i("XXX", "touchRejectionAnimation() called.");

        touchRejectionAnimationInProgress = true;
        rootView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

        // for logging/debugging purposes...
        final String rejectionID = (new Random().nextInt() % 9999999) + "";
        Log.i("XXX", "rejection : " + rejectionID + " started.");

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try { Thread.sleep(200); } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("XXX", "exception in touchRejection() BG thread!");
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.i("XXX", "rejection " + rejectionID + " ending");
                        rootView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                        touchRejectionAnimationInProgress = false;
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        thread.start();

    }

}
```

layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/allowedButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:tag="allowedButton"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/notAllowedButton"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/notAllowedButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:tag="view2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/allowedButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Are you sure your monkey script is not clicking the `allowedButton` and `notAllowedButton`? Can you disable them completely and try again?

Comment: It can and does click both of them by design.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want your onClick() to be triggered on any view click.

Following are the steps which need to take care.

> Create custom viewGroup eg: MyConstraintLayout and add all child
>   inside it.
>
> Override onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) and return it has true.

```
public class MyConstraintLayout extends ConstraintLayout {

    private boolean mIsViewsTouchable;

    public ParentView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ParentView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        inflate(context, R.layout.custom_view, this);
    }

    public ParentView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public void setViewsTouchable(boolean isViewTouchable) {
        mIsViewsTouchable = isViewTouchable;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return mIsViewsTouchable;
    }
 }
```

**Note: Use setViewsTouchable() method as per your requirement, If you pass the parameter as true all views are not clickable if false your views will be clickable.**

Comment: I don't see why this would work since MainActivity.onDispatchTouchEvent() already returns true in my example, and exists *upstream* (happens earlier than) of ViewGroup.onInterceptTouchEvent... but I tried to test this approach you're describing, anyway... but ran into a problem: I can't figure out how to adapt "inflate(context, R.layout.custom_view, this)" to my use-case where the custom ConstraintLayout (MyConstraintLayout) would be the rootview of activity_main.xml.